# What is the exact syntax for using svg font files in @font-face rules

Tags: css, svg, sass, font-face

I am trying to add new font files to my web app. I couldn't find what is the perfect syntax to add svg files in the @font-face rule. My font face rules are in scss format. Below are those.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Brandon";
  src: asset_url("#{$font-reg}.eot");
  src:
    asset_url("#{$font-reg}.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    asset_url("#{$font-reg}.woff2") format("woff2"),
    asset_url("#{$font-reg}.woff") format("woff"),
    asset_url("#{$font-reg}.ttf") format("truetype"),
    asset_url("#{$font-reg}.svg#svgFontName") format("svg");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Brandon";
  src: asset_url("#{$font-bold}.eot");
  src:
    asset_url("#{$font-bold}.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    asset_url("#{$font-bold}.woff2") format("woff2"),
    asset_url("#{$font-bold}.woff") format("woff"),
    asset_url("#{$font-bold}.ttf") format("truetype"),
    asset_url("#{$font-bold}.svg#svgFontName") format("svg");
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

What exactly do I need to put after '#' for the svg file above. I am confused. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Worth noting: svg fonts are only supported by [safari and some older android browser versions. ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_fonts). Since all modern browsers support woff2 or woff, you can safely remove svg font file URLs from your `@font-face` rule. However svg fonts are still handy for re-importing icon sets in fontello or  icomoon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find what to put after the `#` you'd need to open the SVG file in a text editor and find the `<font id="someIdentifier"`.

For example, Fontello generated SVG files have the following line:

`<font id="fontello" horiz-adv-x="1000">`

Which makes the `@font-face` declaration:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontello';
  src: url('../font/fontello.eot');
  src: url('../font/fontello.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../font/fontello.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../font/fontello.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../font/fontello.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../font/fontello.svg#fontello') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

The `#fontello` matches the `id` attribute in that line within the SVG file. You want to match whatever the `id` is within your SVG file.

If your `id` property within the svg file is `id="foobar"`, yours would look like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Brandon";
  src: asset_url("#{$font-reg}.eot");
  src:
    asset_url("#{$font-reg}.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    asset_url("#{$font-reg}.woff2") format("woff2"),
    asset_url("#{$font-reg}.woff") format("woff"),
    asset_url("#{$font-reg}.ttf") format("truetype"),
    asset_url("#{$font-reg}.svg#foobar") format("svg");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Here is official [W3C CSS Fonts Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#src-desc) documentation referencing the `id` property. If you forgot to add the identifier then it would simply reference the first defined font.

> In the case of SVG fonts, the URL points to an element within a
>   document containing SVG font definitions. If the element reference is
>   omitted, a reference to the first defined font is implied. Similarly,
>   font container formats that can contain more than one font must load
>   one and only one of the fonts for a given @font-face rule. Fragment
>   identifiers are used to indicate which font to load. If a container
>   format lacks a defined fragment identifier scheme, implementations
>   should use a simple 1-based indexing scheme (e.g. "font-collection#1"
>   for the first font, "font-collection#2" for the second font).

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot for your help.